# How to sort through 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given the following array...

```
      '0' ...
         'item_id' ...
         'parent_id' => "none"
         'depth' => "0"
         'left' => "1"
         'right' => "30"
     '1' ...
         'item_id' => "1"
         'parent_id' ...
         'depth' => "1"
        'left' => "2"
         'right' => "7"
     '2' ...
         'item_id' => "784657484"
         'parent_id' => "1"
         'depth' => "2"
         'left' => "3"
         'right' => "4"
     '3' ...
         'item_id' => "3"
         'parent_id' => "1"
         'depth' => "2"
         'left' => "5"
         'right' => "6"
```

What would be the best way in javascript to pick off the `item_id` when the `parent_id` is empty and put it into another array.

Comment: Your question is tagged with javascript, but the data structure you showed is not javascript.  Can you please write the data in proper javascript so we might know how to address the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is pseudo code and not actual javascript, I'm guessing it's an array of objects (I've asked you to clarify, but received no response).  So, with that guess this code would create an array of `item_id` values when the `parent_id` was missing or `"none"`:

```
var empties = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!data[i].parent_id || data[i].parent_id === "none") {
        empties.push(data[i].item_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning you assume the data is an array of objects, not a "2D array".

Comment: @bfavaretto - yep, I am guessing the data is an array of objects.  I asked the OP for clarification a little while ago, but no clarification has been provided.